# VSTS Trigger release and deployment after build

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

On my release definitions I have set my environment to have a release trigger so that when a build has been completed with a certain tag, a deployment starts. However after setting this up no release or deployment is started. I think I'm missing something small but can't put my finger on it....

My build tag (added automatically during a build):

[image]

My release trigger:

[image]

What setting(s) need changing to get a release and deployment fired off after my build is ready?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The screenshot is **not your release trigger**, it's your environment trigger.

You can configure when releases should be created, and when those releases should be deployed to environments. The former is configured through [release triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers), and the latter through [environment triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers#env-triggers) - both in a release definition.

[image]

> **You can choose to have the deployment to each environment triggered automatically when a release is created by a continuous deployment
>   trigger.**

The process is changes checked in → CI build triggered → A release created → start deployment to this environment.

More details please refer this tutorial--[Triggers in Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers).

Answer (score 6):

You need to turn on the Continuous deployment trigger under your specific build artifact.

[image: Continuous deployment trigger]